How to store images in local storage and store path in room?
I'm new to Kotlin Jetpack Compose android development and I have been trying to build an app that lets you take notes and you can also store images along with the notes in the room database. The issue is that when I use the following picker to pick images from the gallery they show whilst the app is functioning but as soon as you close and restart the app the images are no longer loading.
Their content uri is stored in the database however. Initially I was storing only the Uris of the content picker which looked like:
content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1001290474

Data Class for the Note in the Room DB
@Entity(tableName = "notes_tbl")
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_title")
    var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_body")
    var desc: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_images")
    var images: List<Uri> = emptyList()
)

Multiple Photo Picker
val multiplePhotoPicker = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(),
        onResult = {
            uris -> uriList.value = uris
        }
    )

Add Note Function (The notesList contains the list of notes fetched from Room)
fun getNote(id: String): Note {
        return notesList.value.first { note -> note.id.toString() == id }
    }

I also tried writing to the storage the images I picked using a code I found here
val saveImageToInternalStorage: (Context, Uri) -> String = {
            context: Context, uri: Uri ->
        val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".jpg"
        val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        inputStream.use {
                input ->
            outputStream.use {
                    output ->
                input?.copyTo(output)
            }
        }
        fileName
    }

They are present in the database but I cannot display them for some reason. I don't know what to do. Kindly overlook any weird code as I tried various methods found online but none worked.

Do you want to store a copy of the images or just a reference?

You forgot to tell us the exception you get when you try to reuse.

There is no exception unfortunately, the app doesn't load the image

A reference would be better but it wasn't working

Your content scheme uri is only valid as long as your app runs or shorter.
In order to be able to use the content uri later you should take persistable uri permission the moment you get that uri.

do you have any resource I can refer as I cannot find anything that tells me how to take that permission via jetpack compose. I tried one method on YouTube but it didn't work

You did not google for take persistable uri permission.
